# Ruby -- Adding the values of sub arrays in an array by their key

Tags: arrays, ruby

So I know how to add all the values in an array.

Example, the sum of [1,2,3,4]...

```
[1,2,3,4].inject(&:+)
#=> 10
```

However, I have an array of arrays and would like to add the values that have the same first element of each sub array.

```
# example
[["A", 10],["A", 5],["B", 5],["B", 5],["C", 15], ["C", 15]]
```

### Desired output:

```
"(A : 15) - (B : 10) - (C : 30)"
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

```
arr = [["A", 10],["A", 5],["B", 5],["B", 5],["C", 15], ["C", 15]]

h = arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |(f,g),h| h[f] += g }
  #=> {"A"=>15, "B"=>10, "C"=>30}
```

Then

```
h.map { |pair| "(%s : %s)" % pair }.join(" - ")
  #=> "(A : 15) - (B : 10) - (C : 30)"
```

which you can combine like so:

```
arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |(f,g),h| h[f] += g }.
    map { |pair| "(%s : %s)" % pair }.join(" - ")
```

See [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-c-new), especially with regards to the use of a default value (here `0`).

Comment: default value of `0` is cleaner than my solution with checking for key presence - good one, as usual!

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [["A", 10],["A", 5],["B", 5],["B", 5],["C", 15], ["C", 15]]
result = a.group_by(&:first).each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), h|
  h[k] = v.map(&:last).inject(:+)
  # if your on Ruby 2.4+ you can write h[k] = v.sum(&:last)
end
#=> {"A"=>15, "B"=>10, "C"=>30}
```

Another option would be to build the hash from the beginning:

```
result = a.each_with_object({}) {|(k, v), h| h[k] = h[k].to_i + v }
#=> {"A"=>15, "B"=>10, "C"=>30}
```

If your desired output is literally a string `"(A : 15) - (B : 10) - (C : 30)"`:

```
result.map { |k, v| "(#{k} : #{v})" }.join(' - ')
#=> "(A : 15) - (B : 10) - (C : 30)"
```

Comment: re your first example, in 2.4.0 we can also do `h[k] = v.sum(&:last)`

Comment: @sagarpandya82 yep, I knew someone would raise it :) edited :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
arr = [["A", 10],["A", 5],["B", 5],["B", 5],["C", 15], ["C", 15]]

arr.group_by(&:first).map { |key, group| [key, group.map(&:last).inject(:+)] } 
# => [["A", 15], ["B", 10], ["C", 30]]
```

How does this work?

- `group_by(&:first)` groups the subarrays by first element
- `map { |key, group| ... }` transforms the groups
- `group.map(&:last).inject(:+)` sums up all last elements in a group

Comment: in 2.4.0 to sum up the elements in a group we can also use `sum` like this: `group.sum(&:last)`.

Answer (score 0):

There are more elegant ways of doing this, but here is the solution as a block, so you can understand the logic...

What this does is :

1. convert the array to a hash, when combining
   values.
2. Then it builds the string, one element at a time, storing
   each in an array.
3. And finally, it combines the array of strings into your desired output.

'

```
my_array = [["A", 10],["A", 5],["B", 5],["B", 5],["C", 15],["C", 15]]
my_hash = {}
output_array = []

my_array.each do |item|
  my_hash[item[0]] ||= 0
  my_hash[item[0]] += item[1]
end

my_hash.each do |k,v|
  output_array.push("(#{k} : #{v})")
end

puts output_array.join(" - ")
```